NestJS: How to override values in .env for unit/e2e tests?
What I'm trying to do is to override values in .env for tests of NestJS apps.
Here's a snippet of my code:
describe('MyController', () => {
  let app: INestApplication;

  beforeAll(async () => {
    const testingModule = await Test.createTestingModule({
      imports: [
        OrmModule.forRoot(OrmConfigForTesting),
        ConfigModule.forRoot({ envVars: ['../.env.test'] }), // This doesn't seem to work
        MyModule, // This gets a value from .env
      ],
    }).compile();
    app = testingModule.createNestApplication();
    await app.init();
  });

  describe('GET /foo', () => {
    // test cases
  });
});


As you could guess, this file case is meant to testing MyModule, which uses values from .env. I have .env.test at the root of the project, which should be used for testing.
The file above doesn't seem to access .env.test (I'm 100% sure that the path used for envVars is currect). Does anyone see why?
